# I am trying to update Font Awesome from 5.0.6 to to 5.8.1, but I am getting blank squares

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Somewhere in my site I have there folders:

- (...)/font-awesome/5.0.6/css/
- (...)/font-awesome/5.0.6/webfonts/
- (...)/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/
- (...)/font-awesome/5.8.1/webfonts/

If I include file `font-awesome/5.0.6/css/fontawesome-all.min.css`, [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome) works.

If I include file `font-awesome/5.8.1/css/fontawesome.min.css`, Font Awesome shows blank squares instead of icons.

It is most likely not due to cache as I've cleared the browser cache and .css cache files.

I remember that in the past, when integrating Font Awesome into a website, I was required to manually change some relative URLs inside the library, but that, if I remember well, was with Font Awesome 4.

I feel however like I'm missing some installation step. I just can't remember since it was "so long ago".

Comment: Sometimes when updating font awesome I have to update my CSS to match the latest version. When we changed the version we were using at the office I changed `font-family: fontAwesome` to `font-family: Font Awesome Pro 5`. Your version may be different

Answer (score 1):

Do you download the .zip file instead of a single `all.min.css` file?
If not, then download the .zip file, unzip it, and link the main CSS file inside the header.

On the other hand, you can use the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) link they provide:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Both work perfectly.

Comment: I had already downoaded the complete .zip. I had tried linking to fontawesome.min.css (which I a-expected to be the main file) and now I head tried linking all.min.css , but I get the same problem.
I've tried the CDN and got the same problem. And in the long term, I don't want to use a CDN.

Comment: Instead of using `fontawesome.min.css` file use `all.min.css` or `all.css`

Comment: It seems like the fonts themselves aren't being downloaded.  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Considering [the last release note](https://fontawesome.com/changelog/latest) there are some big changes done from 5.0 to 5.8:

> Heads Up! This Release Has Breaking Changes
>
> In a recent version, we fixed some issues with using our OTF and TTF font files on mobile projects. The naming, font weight, and version have been modified to be more compatible and stable going forward.
>
> After upgrading your copies of our desktop files, you may need to set the typeface of your text layers again. After doing that, we also recommend double-checking that icons are showing up as expected in your documents. Running into trouble? Get in touch with us and we'll help you out.

You probably need to follow the links there in order to fix your issues:

*[Install the Ligature-based Font Files](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started#install-ligatures)*

---

I also advise you to upgrade slowly to a lower version because actually you are moving by the 7 version and it will difficult to know the real issue. So start moving to 5.1 then 5.2 and so on until you find which version is the culprit.

*[Releases · FortAwesome/Font-Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases)*

Follow *[Upgrading Guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/UPGRADING.md)* for more details about the upgrade between versions.

Comment: I checked the whole upgrading page ... I see things that should not have any impact and things that I just don't understand what they refer to and don't seem to relate to the way I ever used Font Awesome ... like, I'm not using TypeScript, I'm not using Angular, I'm using SVG, I've never needed to "install" fonts ... I usually just included FA's files in my project, called some CSS (in which I only needed to correct some paths) and it was running.

Comment: @TTT did you try to upgrade slowly? test with 5.1 and 5.2 ... to see if it's a general issue or version related issue

Comment: I've just looked for a link to download version 5.1 (or other versions) a minute ago ... didn't find it.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried version 5.1.0 (non-pro). Same problem. (Yet I don't understand if the changlog relates to my usage.)

Comment: @TTT can you use https://jsfiddle.net/ to put all your CSS/HTML code there? and consider the cdn include, let's try to see how your code look

Comment: I've found the issue. It's related to how my site/application is built. I'll post the solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. It's something that is specific to my site/application.

I minify most of my .css files using a PHP library then merge them using a homemade library (only the second library is homemade).
Then because, the resulting .css file isn't in the same locations. Links to webfonts get broken. That was the step I was forgetting: making all the relative ../webfont links semi-relative instead.
Everything works perfectly now.